# Moving data to new MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

I need to transfer data from my old application to new version. The problem is that my new version has more complex DB structure and I don't know exactly what is the best way to move data to new DB.

For example:

OLD TABLE USERS

```
id username  namensurname   email   password   active( ENUM('active', 'blocked')...
```

I need to move that in new DB but new DB is splited into USER table and USER_PROFILE table

```
USER table

id username  name surname  email  password  active(BOOL(0,1))

USER_PROFILE table

id  user_id  phone  status...
```

So my problem is that I need to export all old data but before import to new DB I need to reorganize that data.

For each user I need to create data in USER_PROFILE table

also I need to change role from `enum` to `BOOL` so where there is 'active' in old DB in new should be 1,
for 'blocked' there should be 0.

I know that in new DB I could use for status the same `ENUM` data but that is not the point, Database is more complex, this is just few thing which I think if I find out how to do it I could do all that I need with rest of DB.

SO! Question is:

```
Is it possible, and if it is what is the best way to transfer data.
```

Both applications are developed using Laravel 4

Comment: Is it possible to write a script that maps data from one DB structure to another? Yes. Can SO write it for you? No. Will this question get closed soon? Most likely.

Comment: hey, use MySQL Workbench to manipulate the old DB directly with queries

Answer (score 0):

You can migrate data to the new server with one of these approaches:

- Create a [seed class](http://laravel.com/docs/migrations#database-seeding) that parses old data and insert it in the new database schema. You can benefit of working with the new models instances.
- Create a script that do the migration without using Laravel at all and process data into the database directly.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [package](http://packalyst.com/packages/package/nwidart/db-exporter) that exports your database as a Laravel Migration and all the data as a Seeder class.